# feed an image to android emulator(in genymotion) to mock came

Tags: image, camera, adb, emulation, genymotion

I'm using genymotion in my app tests and realize it's a part from avd and it just use adb.
I found we can append to file **~/Android/Sdk/emulator/resources/Toren1BD.posters**
and feed an image to our emulator camera but it doesn't work for genymotion devices! What should I do?! Do you have any idea?!

Comment: (update): genymotion answered it and said it's not possible even in this new update but it's in their plan. But I want to know is there any way to access dummy camera or change its default?!

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported with Genymotion Desktop yet.

Comment: So you mean isn't there any way for change the default dummy cam?